# XML-Rewrite for frontend only

Tags: xml, url-rewrite

In my custom news-module I got this:

```
<rewrite>
<fancy_url>
<from><![CDATA[/news\/(.+)/]]></from>
<to><![CDATA[news/index/view/title/$1/]]></to>
<complete>1</complete>
</fancy_url>
</rewrite>
```

under the `<global>` section atm.

How can I set this rewrite, to only rewrite frontend?

Edit (Answer 1):
I already use this:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
                <news>
                    <use>admin</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Centano_News</module>
                        <frontName>news</frontName>
                    </args>
                </news>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <news module="news">
            <title>News</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>
            <children>
                <items module="news">
                    <title>Manage News</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>news/adminhtml_news</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </news>
    </menu>
```

And when I change it like you said, it redirects me always to the dashboard when I click "Manage News". May I miss something here :-/

Edit (Answer 2): I thought I could avoid own router. I will try it!

Comment: Is this also rewriting your admin extension? If that's the case please post the url of your adminhtml extension as well

Comment: Yes, thats exactly the problem, its likely the same /index.php/news/... in admin. host/news/newstitle in frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an addition to Sander's answer. You should definitely do what he says.
Also you can add your own router to match urls like `news/something-here`.
For this create a new class in `app/code/[codepool]/[Namespace]/News/Controller/Router.php` - Replace `[codepool]` and `[Namespace]` with the appropriate values.

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_News_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract {
    protected $_restrictedNames = array('index'); //add here other values that should not be matched. I mean don't match urls like `news/index`
    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request){
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $parts = explode('/', $urlKey);
        //check if the url is 'news/something' and the second part in not in the restricted array
        if (count($parts) == 2 && $parts[0] == 'news' && !in_array($parts[0], $this->_restrictedNames)){
            $request->setModuleName('news')
                ->setControllerName('index')
                ->setActionName('view')
                ->setParam('title', $parts[1]);
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $urlKey
            );
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function initControllerRouters($observer){
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('news', $this);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now add in the `config.xml` of the module inside the `<global>` tag, this:

```
<events>
    <controller_front_init_routers>
        <observers>
            <news>
                <class>[Namespace]_News_Controller_Router</class>
                <method>initControllerRouters</method>
            </news>
        </observers>
    </controller_front_init_routers>
</events>
```

And comment out the xml section you posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using the following XML for routing the backend of your extension

```
  ...
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <!-- Includes our controller, so when we add the adminhtml menu item below, it is found! -->
            <adminhtml>
                 <args>
                     <modules>
                         <[module] before="Mage_Adminhtml">[Namespace]_[Module]_Adminhtml</[module]>
                     </modules>
                 </args>
             </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <[module] module="[module]">
                <title>[Module]</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="[module]">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/[module]</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </[module]>
        </menu>
    ...
```

(taken from the [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table#standard_magento_admin_urls_no_rewrite_needed))

This way your extension will start with `/admin/` and won't be rewritten